# Version Control Recommendations

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial

What version control system(s) do people recommend for managing a large set of mostly binary files? The set contains several thousand files, totalling about 8GB and will be growing over time.

We tried GIT and found it was somewhat slow doing that many binary comparisons. Maybe we've configured something wrong?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104453/version-control-for-binaries

Comment: `We tried GIT and found it was somewhat slow doing that many binary comparisons` -- honestly I don't think any system will be really fast at comparing 8 GB from thousands of files

Comment: I'm surprised this was closed...  different version control systems have different access patterns that are well-understood.  This isn't a "what's the best version control tool" question, but a "what's the best version control tool *for this specific scenario*" question.

Answer (score 6):

Version Control tends to be known by another name...  Source Control or Source Code Control.  The name itself suggests exactly what they're built for:  source code - that is, relatively small numbers of relatively small text files.  Most systems can (or at least, *should*) be able to handle large repositories of large binaries as well, with varying degrees of success.

### Version Control Systems

There are roughly three main types of version control tools, and each has various tradeoffs when it comes to storing version control.  But when you have a large repository of large binaries, these design decisions can make or break.

1. **Edit/Merge/Commit Systems** like CVS and Subversion are not going to solve this problem well.  In these types of systems, when you fetch code from the server, the files will be created in your working directory and are created read/write.  In addition, the client will store some mechanism for determining if you have changed these files locally - this could be a hash of the file contents as they exist on the server, or it could be a copy of the "baseline" file without edits.  When you want to determine what's changed on your filesystem, your version control client will compare your working directory to the baseline to tell you what files you've edited.

   These types of systems tend to not scale well to multi-GB repositories with multi-GB files.  Some tools may be okay if you are very careful about your usage patterns - for example, you may be able to limit the scope of these tools by avoiding UI front-ends and instead explicitly providing the paths you are checking in (instead of scanning the entire working directory.)

   In addition, if you choose a tool that uses whole baseline files, you will need double the amount of disk space - 8GB for your resources and another 8GB for the baseline files.
2. **Distributed Version Control Systems** like git and mercurial are also not likely to be the best performers here.  DVCS tools have [radically different history models](http://www.ericsink.com/entries/dvcs_dag_1.html) than your centralized edit/merge/commit systems, but most of the tools are similar in that when you want to determine your working directory's status, they'll compare the files in the directories to see what's changed.

   Here too, your disk space requirements will grow.  Since distributed systems store a copy of the repository, locally, you'll need at least as much space for the repository as for your working folder - and this is a best-case scenario and assumes that your system supports "shallow" history, where it *doesn't* store all the historic versions of your files.

   Some DVCS tools have a [binary or "large file" mode or plug-in](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BigfilesExtension) wherein large files are placed on a central server instead of in your local repository.  This sort of hybrid approach definitely has merit, especially when you don't *always need* those big files.  Otherwise, you can get into a situation where you have all of the complexity of a centralized version control system combined with all of the complexity of a DVCS.
3. **Checkout/Edit/Checkin Systems** like Team Foundation Server and Perforce are likely the most suitable version control systems for this.  In these types of systems, when you fetch code from the server, the files will be created in your working directory and are set to read-only.  This is because you are to instruct the tool when you begin editing these files, at which point your client will set them read-write.  Your client (or the server) then maintains a list of the changes you have made.  When you have finished editing them, you can check them in to the server.

   These types of systems are advantageous when you have very large (multi-GB) repositories and/or very large (multi-GB) files, because you do not have to examine the working folder for changes or diff files.

   Note that some systems may be able to work in either mode.  TFS 2012, for example, uses an edit/merge/commit model by default (called *"local workspaces"*), but can be made to use a checkout/edit/checkin model (called *"server workspaces"*) explicitly.

(Note, I borrowed [Eric Sink's terminology](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/scm_checkins.html) here, but considering he wrote a book on Version Control systems, I think these are appropriately authoritative.)

### Digital Asset Management

If your big repository of multi-GB files happens to not be just random data, and is instead...  graphics or audio, then you might be best avoiding a version control system altogether and aiming at a [Digital Asset Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_asset_management) tool designed specifically for that purpose.

Some of these tools (like Quark Publishing System and K4) are aimed at the publishing sector, some (like Adobe VersionCue) are aimed at the graphics design and illustration sector.  Some of these tools (like Alienbrain) even have Visual Studio plug-ins in an attempt to entice game development studios who do heavy graphics and audio work as well as write code.

If you happen to work in game development, there's several good answers to this question on the [Game Development site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/480/version-control-for-game-development-issues-and-solutions).